# Output domain URL just as text by using TypoScript

Tags: constants, typo3, typoscript

In my HTML-template I have placed a logo surrounded by an `<a>`-tag. My purpose with this is to refer to the homepage by using just as much TypoScript as realy necessary. I searched in TSref and official forums on that but just came across a solution already creating this link by using `stdWrap` which is exactly what I not want. Is it possible to keep it that simple that I only need to place a marker within the `<a>`-tag inside my HTML-template?
I thought of something like this: `<a href="###HOMELINK###">logo image here</a>` and then using ...`marks.HOMELINK = TEXT` in the TS template record.
I simply don't want to get things parsed twice which already can be achieved by simple markup in my HTML-template.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to use the below typoscript:

```
lib.logo = IMAGE
lib.logo.file = fileadmin/templates/logo.gif
lib.logo.stdWrap.typolink.parameter = 1      #home page id
```

or

```
lib.logo = COA
lib.logo{
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        typolink{
            parameter = 1
            returnLast = url
        }
        wrap = |">
    }
    20 = IMAGE
    20{
        file= fileadmin/templates/images/logo.png
        altText = Logo
    }
    wrap = <div id="logo"><a id="logo_image" href="|</a></div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can hard code it in your HTML file like this:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=2"><img src="fileadmin/img/logo.png" /></a>
```

Where /index.php?id= number of your homepage. To view homepage number just hover your mouse over your backend tree and ull see it or use:

```
options.pageTree.showPageIdWithTitle = 1
```

in your User Settings to get all PageId's in backend tree to help u.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, that would work indeed, but hardcoding such is not a good way to go when working on templates (since the approach of them should be the ability to reuse em on further projects with minimum modifications). This would also have the drawback of hardcoding having to get my hands on this HTML passage again if I decided to have nice looking URLs later. Thanks anyway!